# Need to persist values from one record to the subsequent record - lag and retain both work but not giving desired results

Tags: arrays, sas, sas-macro, do-loops

I am editing my original question to simplify the problem statement:

I need to create a dataset that contains the principal paydown schedule of a security, which is split into 3 tranches. For each period for the security, I need to calculate the ending balances of principal owed for each tranche. For period 0 (i.e. starting period), I already have the balances owed. For subsequent periods, I need to take the balances from the previous periods and subtract the principal paid down in the current period. The same logic should continue through the last period.

In my SAS code, I am able to get period 1 to do the calculations correctly, but the balances from period 1 don't correctly make it into period 2, causing the calculation to break from that point onwards. I know lag or its placement is what is not working correctly. I am not able to figure out where to place it, or how to use retain (if not lag), such that my balances go from one row to the next.

```
%let n_t=3;
data xyz;
INFILE DATALINES DLM='#';
input ID $6.    period PrincipalPaid  best12.2;
datalines;
ABC123#00#0.0
ABC123#01#4.0
ABC123#02#3.92
ABC123#03#3.84
ABC123#04#3.76
ABC123#05#3.69
ABC123#06#3.62
ABC123#07#3.54
;run;


data xyz2;
set xyz;
by id;

if period=0 then do;

    Bal1= 120;
    Bal2= 8;
    Bal3= 2;

end;

/*Code to push all starting balances from period 0 to 1*/

array prev_bal{&N_t.} prev_bal1-prev_bal&n_t.;
array bal{&N_t.} bal1-bal&n_t.;

do i=1 to &N_t.;
prev_bal{i}=lag(bal{i});
end;

/*code to calculate balances for periods >=1*/
if period>=1 then do;

    array PrincipalPayDown{&N_t.} PrincipalPayDown1-PrincipalPayDown&N_t.;

    do i = 1 to &N_t. ;     
        PrincipalPayDown{i}=round(PrincipalPaid*prev_bal{i}/sum(of prev_bal:),0.01);
        bal{i}=max(prev_bal{i}-PrincipalPayDown{i},0);
    end;
end;

drop i ;            

run;

proc sql;
create table final as
select
id,period,PrincipalPaid,prev_bal1,prev_bal2,prev_bal3,
PrincipalPayDown1,PrincipalPayDown2,PrincipalPayDown3,Bal1,Bal2,Bal3
from xyz2;
quit;
```

I am also adding a picture of the final dataset with the correct output calculated in Excel. I want SAS to give me the same output for periods >=2.

[Screenshot showing correct output in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ethxh.png)

Comment: What is the actual input data?  Which variables are input? Do you really need more observations than just the starting balance?  Please share the input as actual text, preferable as a data step.

Comment: Hi @Tom, I just updated the code to add input data

Comment: Your sample data only has one ID. Do we really need all 60 periods to test the logic?  Also did you really want SAS to insert a decimal point before the last two digits of DEFAUTLS if the value on the datalines did not include a decimal point?  Normally there is no need to use an informat to read numeric values and you didn't use one for any of the other numeric variables.  And when you do use an informat you only specify decimal places if the strings being read have explicitly removed the decimal point to save space on the line.

Comment: You have not really explained how the results you get are different than what you want.

Comment: Where are the tranches defined?

Comment: What is the meaning of RIF after the first period?  Why does it change?  Does that reflect some type of payment that was received?  What do the other two input variables mean?

Comment: RIF is the total amount of risk inforce (Which , in this context, is the loan balance that the insurer is carrying risk for). RIF goes down as the borrower makes payments on the loan. I don't necessarily need all 61 rows to test the logic, even the first 5 will do.  there are 10 tranches in the deal. the starting balance of each tranche is defined in the snippet that multiplies rif by different hardcoded factors. As far as how I wrote the data step for the input data goes, I have had 0 experience doing that because my data is typically available on a SAS server. So it's clearly novice :)

Comment: The logic I have created is correctly calculating RIF_PD , LOSS_PD, and BAL_ arrays correctly for period 1. But it doesn't calculate these for periods >=2. I think it has to do with the fact that the fields total_bal and sub_bal are not correctly pushed into the fields prev_total_bal and prev_sub_bal. I am struggling with finding a solution for that.

Comment: I suspect you want to retain the calculated variables instead of trying to use LAG() on them.  Show a more manageable example.  Instead of showing one id with 60 periods and 10 tranches use say two id values for 3 periods and 3 tranches.  Show the input and the desired output. Explain the meaning of the steps in words illustrated by the actual numbers in your example input and example results.

Comment: Agree - `lag` is almost always the harder way to do these things, `retain` almost always easier, but show us a simpler example so it's not going to take a masters in finance to answer the question :)

Comment: I hear you, and this is definitely not easy to explain over this forum :). I tried putting together an example in Excel but I realized I can't attach files here. You can however, see a screenshot of the sample excel example.

Comment: Why doesn't the sample input you posted match the photograph of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Post it on communities.sas.com, you can include attachments. Make sure to include your input and the matched output.

Comment: Tom, Joe, Reeza - I changed the body of my question to make sure the code matches the Excel sample input/output.